# NHibernate SetFetchMode doesn't work with nested criteria

Tags: c#, nhibernate, detachedcriteria

Assuming I run the following code:

```
var placementCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<ResidentialPlacementClientService>();
placementCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Le("StartDate", effectiveDate));
placementCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Ge("EndDate", effectiveDate));
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("CaseClient.CaseFile", FetchMode.Eager);
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("CaseClient.Incomes", FetchMode.Eager); 
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("CaseClient.ClientProfile", FetchMode.Eager);
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("CaseClient.ClientProfile.Person", FetchMode.Eager);
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("VendorService", FetchMode.Eager);
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("VendorService.Vendor", FetchMode.Eager);

using (var session = OpenSession())
{
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        residentialPlacements = placementCriteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List<ResidentialPlacementClientService>();
    }
}
```

The "Incomes" property on my is populated correctly.

Now when I add criteria on incomes, the property is no longer being fetched eagerly.

```
var placementCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<ResidentialPlacementClientService>();
placementCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Le("StartDate", effectiveDate));
placementCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Ge("EndDate", effectiveDate));
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("CaseClient.CaseFile", FetchMode.Eager);
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("CaseClient.Incomes", FetchMode.Eager); 
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("CaseClient.ClientProfile", FetchMode.Eager);
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("CaseClient.ClientProfile.Person", FetchMode.Eager);
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("VendorService", FetchMode.Eager);
placementCriteria.SetFetchMode("VendorService.Vendor", FetchMode.Eager);


var caseClientCriteria = placementCriteria.CreateCriteria("CaseClient", JoinType.InnerJoin);

var incomesCriteria = caseClientCriteria.CreateCriteria("Incomes", JoinType.InnerJoin);
incomesCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Le("StartDate", effectiveDate));

incomesCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Or(Restrictions.Ge("EndDate", effectiveDate),
                                    Restrictions.IsNull("EndDate")));

incomesCriteria.Add(Restrictions.Eq("IncomeType", incomeType));

using (var session = OpenSession())
{
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        residentialPlacements = placementCriteria.GetExecutableCriteria(session).List<ResidentialPlacementClientService>();
    }
}
```

Why does NHibernate do this?  How can I change my query/criteria so that the property is fetched eagerly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you have filters on an association then NH cant be sure that all entities of the association are returned to initialize the association collection. you can issue a Select for the ids and then fetch the entities with associations eagerly

```
...
placementCriteria.SetProjection(Projections.Id());

residentialPlacements = session.CreateCriteria<ResidentialPlacementClientService>()
    .Add(Subqueries.In("Id", placementCriteria))
    .SetFetchMode("CaseClient.CaseFile", FetchMode.Eager);
    .SetFetchMode("CaseClient.Incomes", FetchMode.Eager); 
    .SetFetchMode("CaseClient.ClientProfile", FetchMode.Eager);
    .SetFetchMode("CaseClient.ClientProfile.Person", FetchMode.Eager);
    .SetFetchMode("VendorService", FetchMode.Eager);
    .SetFetchMode("VendorService.Vendor", FetchMode.Eager);
    .List<ResidentialPlacementClientService>();
```

Comment: Thanks,  I'll give it a try today and will mark as answer once I get it working.

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thanks for taking the time to explain why my original method wasn't working.