# Eager loading of many-to-many relation by QueryOver in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I have a many-to-many relation between Course and Group entities

Course (1:n) Course-Group (n:1) Group

- Course(Name,CourseGroups of type Course-Group ...)
- Group(Name,GroupsCourses of type Course-Group...)
- Course-Group(Course,Group,...)

I want to select Course and related Course-Group and Group

This is my query

```
QueryOver.Of<Course>().JoinQueryOver<Course-Group>(c => c.CourseGroups).Fetch(cf=>CourseGroups).Eager
.JoinQueryOver<Group>(cg => cg.Group).**[Fetch(cg => cg.Group).Eager.]**
DetachedCriteria
```

C# Compiler report error for section in the bracket

How can I query a many-To-many relation as above?

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to fetch them eagerly

```
var query = QueryOver.Of<Course>()
    .Fetch(c => c.CourseGroups).Eager
    .Fetch(c => c.CourseGroups.Group).Eager;
```

otherwise there's only subqueries, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8142710/nhibernate-setfetchmode-doesnt-work-with-nested-criteria/8149006#8149006) why

Answer (score 0):

You have to future in the collections you want otherwise you'll end up with Cartesian products. See this link for more information about what that looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5683564/764805